# Is it possible to align a paragraph that contains different font sizes to middle in iText?

Tags: java, itext

```
public static final Font BLUE = new Font(FontFamily.HELVETICA, 6, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLUE);
public static final Font RED = new Font(FontFamily.HELVETICA, 15, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.RED);
Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
p.add(new Chunk("small middle", BLUE));
p.add(new Chunk("big middle", RED));
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(p);
cell.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
```

This snippet aligns the texts to the middle relative to the chunk with the bigger size. Is it possible that both chunks would align to the middle with respect to their own font sizes?

Comment: Could you add a sketch comparing what happens to what you want? I don't quite understand it as written now.

Comment: When I add 2 chunks with different font sizes to a paragraph and try to align it in middle vertically, the text aligns to the chunk with bigger font size thus the smaller text aligns to the baseline of the larger text. I can align it properly when I separate the chunks in different cells, but I want the chunks to be in same cell.

Answer (score 0):

Well, a major property of a line in a paragraph is that all the characters on that line (unless subscripted or superscripted) share the same baseline.

So you might try superscripting the smaller chunk a bit like this to get where you want:

```
Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
Chunk smallChunk = new Chunk("small middle", BLUE);
smallChunk.setTextRise( (15 - 6) / 2);
p.add(smallChunk);
p.add(new Chunk("big middle", RED));
```